# service launched at boot, after all other?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, boot, services

> Config : Linux Mint 17,2 (Ubuntu based, Debian based).

I launch a home-made service at boot. Added with `update-rc.d homemadeserviceName defaults`

I need to be sure homemadeserviceName runs after all orthers.

How can I do that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To start your service at the end, run this command

```
update-rc.d homemadeserviceName defaults 99
```

This will add a link inside `/etc/rc.d` as,

```
S99homemadeserviceName
```

Upstart will start services in the order of their numeric suffix... S0, S1, S2... and finally S99 services.

Comment: there is also a command to list all service & their level/priority